# Table overlapping text in conference document class

Tags: tables, spacing, texmaker

I have a problem with my table overlapping my text. I give the MWE and a picture of the result:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{amsmath} % matrices
\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\section{Conclusions and future work}

The results indicated that aerial gamma-ray spectrometry and topographical data can be used to detect soil types up to approximately 44 \% accuracy using multinomial logistic regression. An increase in the accuracy was achieved using 8-nearest neighbour classifier, which achieved approximately 50 \% accuracy. We noted that especially sandy till and sphagnum peat had good prediction accuracies when compared with other soil types. When considering low water permeability soil types, the prediction accuracy was higher.

There is a possibility to use aerial Light Detection and Ranging (LiDAR)\  data instead of the NTS elevation model. This would enable surface texture features and better post-processing capability to predict the actual soil types. This remains a subject of the further study.      

Given the predicted hydraulic conduction layer, additional expert rules or machine learning methods can be used to select the soil type from several possible. Such expert rules exists but are not yet implemented. 


\begin{table}
    \small
    \captionsetup[table]{skip=15pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{center}

        \vspace{0.3cm}

        \begin{tabular}{| p{8mm} | p{8mm} | p{8mm} | p{8mm} | p{8mm} | p{8mm} | p{8mm} |            p{8mm} | p{8mm} | p{8mm} | }
        \hline
        \cellcolor{gray!25}1206 & 731 & 225 & 228 & 244 & 43 & 11 & 19 & 12 & 8 \\ \hline
        18448 & \cellcolor{gray!25}90820 & 43255 & 2299 & 10058 & 2299 & 835 & 395 &                11627 & 11042 \\ \hline
        1530 & 14061 & \cellcolor{gray!25}19642 & 36 & 1161 & 1631 & 2599 & 1460 & 5512 &       3860 \\ \hline
        0 & 6 & 0 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 167 & 35 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ \hline
        0 & 1 & 0 & 3 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 \\ \hline
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        162 & 1804 & 504 & 44 & 181 & 547 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 4195 & 999 & 457 & 4 \\              \hline
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        429 & 3444 & 3029 & 28 & 609 & 369 & 68 & 73 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 7948 & 7078 \\            \hline
        765 & 8403 & 8707 & 15 & 1727 & 148 & 0 & 0 & 17252 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 27969 \\       \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
    \small
    \captionsetup[table]{skip=15pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{center}
        \captionof{table}{Test} 
        \vspace{0.3cm}

        \begin{tabular}{| p{8mm} | p{8mm} | p{8mm} | p{8mm} | p{8mm} | p{8mm} | p{8mm} |            p{8mm} | p{8mm} | p{8mm} | }
        \hline
        \cellcolor{gray!25}1206 & 731 & 225 & 228 & 244 & 43 & 11 & 19 & 12 & 8 \\ \hline
        18448 & \cellcolor{gray!25}90820 & 43255 & 2299 & 10058 & 2299 & 835 & 395 &                11627 & 11042 \\ \hline
        1530 & 14061 & \cellcolor{gray!25}19642 & 36 & 1161 & 1631 & 2599 & 1460 & 5512 &       3860 \\ \hline
        0 & 6 & 0 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 167 & 35 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ \hline
        0 & 1 & 0 & 3 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 \\ \hline
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        162 & 1804 & 504 & 44 & 181 & 547 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 4195 & 999 & 457 & 4 \\              \hline
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
        429 & 3444 & 3029 & 28 & 609 & 369 & 68 & 73 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 7948 & 7078 \\            \hline
        765 & 8403 & 8707 & 15 & 1727 & 148 & 0 & 0 & 17252 &\cellcolor{gray!25} 27969 \\       \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}




\vspace{1cm}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

 \vspace*{2mm}
\bibitem[Azz94]{Azz94}
  A. Azzalini, P.J. Diggle.
  \emph{Prediction of soil respiration rates from temperature, moisture and soil type}.
  Journal of the Royal Statistical Society - Series C: Applied Statistics,
  1994.

    \vspace*{2mm}
\bibitem[Gao10]{Gao10}
  H. Gao, Q. Tang, X. Shi, C. Zhu, T.J. Bohn, F. Su, J. Sheffield, M. Pan, D.P. Lettenmaier, E.F. Wood.
  \emph{Water budget record from variable infiltration capacity
(vic) model. Algorithm Theoretical Basis Document
for Terrestrial Water Cycle Data Records},
  2010.

    \vspace*{2mm}
\bibitem[Gon05]{Gon05}
  M. G\"onen, G. Heller.
  \emph{Concordance probability and discriminatory power in proportional}. Biometrika,
92:965–970,
  2005.

   \vspace*{2mm}
\bibitem[Kiss04]{Kiss04}
  R. Kiss.
  \emph{Determination of drainage network in digital
elevation models, utilities and limitations}. Journal of
Hungarian Geomathematics, 2:16–29,
  2004.

 \vspace*{2mm}
\bibitem[Ram03]{Ram03}
  A.T. Ramli, A.T. Rahman, M.H. Lee.
  \emph{Statistical prediction of terrestrial gamma radiation dose rate based on geological features and soil types in Kota Tinggi district, Malaysia}.
  Department of Physics, Faculty of Science, Universiti Teknologi Malaysia Skudai, Johore 81310, Malaysia,
  2003.

 \vspace*{2mm}
\bibitem[Scul04]{Scul04}
  P. Sculla, J. Franklin, O.A. Chadwick.
  \emph{The application of classification tree analysis to soil type prediction in a desert landscape}.
  Ecological Modelling 181.
  Department of Geography, Colgate University, 13 Oak Drive, Hamilton, NY 13346, USA, 2004.

 \vspace*{2mm}
\bibitem[Schu05]{Schu05}
  R.P.O. Schulte, J. Diamond, K. Finkele, N.M. Holden, A.J. Brereton.
  \emph{Predicting the soil moisture conditions of Irish grasslands}.
  Irish Journal of Agricultural and Food Research.
  Teagasc, Johnstown Castle Environmental Research Centre, Wexford,
  2005.

    \vspace*{2mm}
\bibitem[Zach12]{Zach12}
  J.V.A. Zachary.
  \emph{Using topographic and soils data to understand and predict field scale moisture patterns}.
  Graduate thesis, Iowa State University,
  2012.


\end{thebibliography}



\end{document}
```

[image]

In the conference document class the paper is divided into two columns. But what if I want to add a big picture or table that would require the whole width of the page? How can I make the text to follow the aligning as is specified in the conference document class but so that it wouldn't overlap the table or picture?

Thnx for any help!

Comment: Those tables are simply too wide. You can use `table*` to make a two-column float. Or you could set your table in an even smaller font size.

Comment: You should also have a look at package `siunitx`. Havin is linebreak in a number-unit-pair is *bad*.

Comment: Okay, thank you :) I was just thinking if there is some way around this?...I mean, If I would want them to be wider